# Regcomp is throwing segmentation fault

Tags: gcc, gdb

Segmentation fault: On the line where regcomp is used it is throwing segmentation fault.
I have used gdb for running the program.

I am trying:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
#define LINE_LENGTH 256

main()
{
  char *c_char;
  char *cp;
  char *temp;
  regex_t regex;
  int reg = 0;
  char f_input[] = {"path/path/.pc"};
  FILE *input;

 input = fopen(f_input, "r");
 while (fgets(temp, LINE_LENGTH, input) != NULL)
 {
  temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*LINE_LENGTH);
  if((cp = strstr(temp, "#define")) != NULL)
  {
    temp +=7;
    memset(c_char, '\0', sizeof(char)*50);
    c_char = strtok(temp, " ");
    reg = regcomp(&regex, "^[A-Z]", 0);
    reg = regexec(&regex, c_char, 0, NULL, 0);

    if (reg == REG_NOMATCH)
    {
      fprintf("%s should be in upper case.", c_char);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

After coming to the line:  "reg = regcomp(&regex, "^[A-Z]", 0);" i tried to print regex value...
"p regex".
It prints:

```
"{buffer = 0x0, allocated = 0, used = 0, syntax = 0, fastmap = 0x0.........}"
```

Comment: Your question provides approximately zero information, and can't be answered. What made you think the lines of code you provided have anything to do with the actual crash? What is the crash stack trace?

Comment: Hi, I as not able to paste the code or any other screenshot, so i have edited the code above. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I think the crash can be caused by this code:

```
memset(c_char, '\0', sizeof(char)*50);
```

when you program starts `c_char` is uninitialized:

```
main()
{
  char *c_char;
```

Then in the `while` loop when you first call memset() 'c_char' is still uninitialized. As a result you pass an invalid pointer to `memset()`